# Array is storing one character in each field PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form

```
<form action="inserir.php" method="POST">
<tr>
<td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td>
<td><input type='text' name='ppdata[$x]'/></td>
<td><input type='text' size='40' name='ppempresa[$x]'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='ppfuncao[$x]' size='40'></td>
</tr>`
</form>`
```

In my code, the user can insert more rows to the table, insert data and send it to a new file (insert.php)

```
foreach ($_POST["ppdata"] as $dat){
echo $dat. ' ';
}

foreach ($_POST["ppempresa"] as $empresa){
echo $empresa. ' ';
}

foreach ($_POST["ppfuncao"] as $funcao){
echo $funcao. ' ';
}



$data = count($dat);
$emp = count($empresa);
$func = count($funcao);


if($data == $emp){
  for($x = 0; $x < $emp; $x++){
    $str[] = "('{$dat[$x]}','{$empresa[$x]}','{$funcao[$x]}','{$id}')";
  }
  $s = implode(',',$str);
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pp (data,empresa,descricao,id_user) VALUES $s;");
}
```

The array i'm seng only saves one char per field.
if i do:

```
echo '$dat';
```

It'll echo the whole array.

If i do this:

```
echo '$dat[0]';
```

It'll only show the first letter of the string. If i write 'Hello' on the input, It will only show 'H'.

EDIT: I need to insert data in the database, depending on how much rows the user adds. but right now, the array only inserts the last letter of the last word of each field.

Comment: Is `$dat` an array? Otherwise each letter will count as an index as they would in an array. It would help if we could see what type of information your trying to store in the variable, and what you are expecting to see?

Comment: $dat is an array gotten from the POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what happens when you write "Hello".

The following POST array is sent:

```
$_POST = array(
    "ppdata" => array(
        "Hello"
    )
);
```

Now, you run this:

```
foreach ($_POST["ppdata"] as $dat){
echo $dat. ' ';
}
```

At this point, `$dat` is equal to `"Hello"`.

Notably, `$dat` is a *string*. This means that `$dat[0]` is the first character of the string, namely `"H"`. That is how accessing a string as an array of characters works.

You probably meant to use `$_POST['ppdata']` everywhere you used `$dat` (in `count`, in the loop etc.) as this is your array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i need to insert the whole array to a database, and it only write the last letter of the last word of the array... (forgot to mention this, sorry)

Comment: $dat is an array gotten from the POST

Comment: If that were true, your `echo $dat` would yield `Array`.